# StackOverflowError whilst creating object

Tags: java, oop, object, recursion, stack-overflow

So this is just a part of my code where I'm trying to make an object. All I added was the body of the constructor. It could be something else wrong in my code but I just wanted to check if this is how to create an artist object. I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

and at tss.Artist. (Artist.java:26) is listed many many many times. I'm just a confused java noob. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
public Artist(String name) {
      Artist artist = new Artist(name);
}
```

Comment: Thats infinite loop...
You create a object "Artist" every time you creating a object "artist"...

Comment: You are making infinite recursion here, thats why you got stack overflow. In your constructor you're calling the same constructor and so on, until your stack is full.

Comment: This is where stepping through the code in your debugger would be the fastest way to see what your code is doing and why.

Comment: @Wufo it's infinite, but ot a loop, rather a recursive call

Comment: @Stultuske yeah, you're right. It's a recursive call...

Answer (score 2):

Just take a close look at that method:

```
public Artist(String name) {
    Artist artist = new Artist(name);
}
```

The constructor of thet object is invoking itself. You have an infinite loop and `StackOverflowError` is thrown.

Comment: Okay, yeah that makes a lot of sense. Thanks

Comment: @zzzzzz no problem, if you find it helpful, consider upvoting / marking as correct;)

Answer (score 1):

You are `recursively calling the constructor` without `any terminating condition` that leads an `infinite stack of the constructor call`.

```
public Artist(String name) {
    Artist artist = new Artist(name);
}
```

Your `new Artist(name)` will call the constructor `public Artist(String name)` and which again calls `new Artist(name)` and this will be going on still the method stack gets full.

Answer (score 1):

A Constructor is used to instantiate any object. While you add a constructor in your class [ in your case, a parameterised constructor ], just use it for initialisation purpose.

```
public Artist(String name) {
  this.name = name;  // you have private variable called name in your class
 }
```

If you instantiate object within constructor, it will end up in a never ending loop and ultimately you will have StackOverFlow error.

Answer (score 0):

I see you question (code) in two parties: create constructor and create object of class. In next example I put class there to show the structure of the code.

```
//class should look like this ...
public class Artist {
    String artistName;
    //other attributes

    //create constructor
    public Artist(String name){
        this.artistName = name;    
    }
}


//Next two line can be placed in other class 
//(e.g. 1st line in class containing main function and 2st line in main function)
//create object/instance of class
Artist artist = new Artist(name);

//Use create instance of that class
System.out.println(artist.artistName);
```